# Placing links over an image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a navigation bar. The background consists of an image, and I'm using text placeholders until I have the links sorted. I cannot seem to get the text to appear on the navigation bar, rather they insist on appearing below in a list style.

An example:
[image]
The grey gradiented bar is intended to be the navigation bar.

HTML:

```
<div id="pagewrapper">
<div id="container">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
    <div id="center">
        <div id="pagebanner">
        <img src="img/banner.png" />
        </div>

        <div id="navibar">
        <img src="img/navibar.png">
        <div class="naviitems">
        Home
        </div>
        <div class="naviitems">
        PHolder1
        </div>
        <div class="naviitems">
        PHolder2
        </div>
        <div class="naviitems">
        PHolder3
        </div>
        <div class="naviitems">
        Contact Us
        </div>
        </img>
        </div>

        <div id="pagecontent">
        <h1>Oh no, I broke my elephant!</h1>
        <p>Wiggle!</p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

And the corresponding CSS:

```
#container{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:1017px;
    text-align:center;
}
#left{
    float:left;
    width:160px;
    height:900px;
    background-color: #D8D8D8;
}
#right{
    float:right;
    width:160px;
    height:900px;
    background-color: #D8D8D8;
}
#center{
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 697px;

}
#pagebanner{
display: inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 697px;
}
#navibar{
display: inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 697px;
    height: 27px;
}
.naviitems{
margin: 0 auto;
height:25px;
width:20%;
}
#pagecontent{
display: inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 697px;
}
```

Comment: #navibar should be display block, and .naviitems should be display inline-block.

Comment: @BrianGlaz Thanks, that's part of the way there. http://i.imgur.com/2UGIs7Z.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the background property of the parent DIV to the image instead of calling it using an IMG tag.

```
.navibar {
background:url(URLofImage)
}
```

Comment: Is `:url` the same if the path is local? or can I use background-image?

Comment: Should be, and without the quotes around it. Also, to keep it from tiling add no-repeat after (URLofImage)

Comment: Erm... actually, this didn't work at all. I tried brackets, quotation marks, an equals sign...

Edit: Nope, it did work. I forgot a semi-colon.

Comment: Try using single quotes(apostrophes) around it like 'img/navibar.png'

Answer (score 1):

I used

```
background: linear-gradient(180deg, #777, #eee);
```

instead of a background image, see if it fits your needs... [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qhvsbu5d/)